# Error when attempting to implement page object model using cucumber.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

I am attempting to implement a page object pattern for my cucumber.js test automation suite with selenium webdriver. However when I attempt to call the page object from my test step I get an error. My folder structure is as follows:

```
features
|__pages - login_page.js
|__steps - login_steps.js
|__support - world.js
```

Feature file is fairly straight forward:

```
Feature File

Scenario: Login 
Given I browse to the login page
When I enter the username "test" and password "test"
Then I should be logged in successfully
```

My login page is as follows:

```
'use strict';

exports.login = function () {
   this.driver.get('https://www.example.com/login');
   this.driver.findElement({ id: 'username' }).sendKeys('my username');
   this.driver.findElement({ id: 'password' }).sendKeys('my password');
   this.driver.findElement({ id: 'btn-login'}).click();
};
```

My steps definition file is:

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var loginpage = require('../pages/LoginPage');


module.exports = function() {
   this.World = require('../support/world.js').World;

   this.Given(/^I enter the username "(.*)", and password (.*)"$/, function (username, password) {
//call page object
    loginpage.login();

    });


};
```

However when I run the test I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
      at Object.exports.login (/Users/Gerry/cuke/features/pages/LoginPage.js:9:16)
```

which corresponds to the line: this.driver.get('https://www.example.com/login');

The above steps from the login function work fine if I plug them directly into the steps (not calling page object).

Anybody got any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure this out. The problem was that the context of 'this' in the steps did not match the context in the page object. I needed to pass the current context of 'this' into the page function. So my steps now looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;
var loginpage = require('../../pages/LoginPage');
var World = require('../support/world.js').World;

module.exports = function() {
  this.World = World;
  this.Given(/^I enter the following login credentials "(.*)", and " (.*)"$/, function (username, password) {

    // We need to pass the current context of `this` so we can access
    // the driver in the page function
    loginpage.login(this, username, password);
});
```

and my login page function now looks like this:

```
'use strict';
exports.login = function (context, username, password) {
   context.driver.get('https://www.getturnstyle.com/login');
   context.driver.findElement({ id: 'username' }).sendKeys(username);
   context.driver.findElement({ id: 'password' }).sendKeys(password);
   context.driver.findElement({ id: 'btn-login'}).click();
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Comment: I know this thread is old but if possible could you please post your world.js file for reference? I am new to cucumber js and trying to look at how you have implemented it.